# Record Split using Spark HiveContext based on Header Record

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a single file like below which contains the data combined from 4 different files into a single file from the source system.

The NEWFILE= is the separator of the data. For example all the data after the line NEWFILE=STUDENT and till the line NEWFILE=SUBJECT belongs to STUDENT file. The issue is we don't have any pattern to separate the records of each file. Also the source system cannot separate the file into 4 files.

I need to load this single input file and separate the records as per the header of the record.

I got the below logic working in Hive but when I tried to convert the same into Spark jobs, I am getting error as "block__offset__inside__file" is unknown to spark. I tried to find the alternative for the "block__offset__inside__file" in spark but it seems there is no alternative as the JIRA link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8006

I am in a situation where I can only use Hive queries in Spark using HiveContext/SQLContext for this transformation.

I want to check if it is feasible to convert the below hive query in Spark SQL.

If not possible in Spark SQL, then how can i apply the similar logic in Spark as spark transformations are parallel and distributed. I don't think we can use the accumulator for the row # identification..

**Working SQL in Hive**
select      testfield
           ,headerno
           ,row_number () over
            (
                partition by    fileno
                order by        headerno
            )   as recordnumber

from       (select  testfield
                   ,block__offset__inside__file     as headerno

```
               ,count(case when testfield like 'NEWFILE=%' then 1 end) over
                (
                    partition by    input__file__name
                    order by        block__offset__inside__file
                ) as fileno


        from    test
        ) inner
```

;

The file content data is given below

```
NEWFILE=STUDENT
100 XYZ
101 ABC
102 DEF
NEWFILE=SUBJECT
1 ENGLISH
2 MATHS
NEWFILE=TEACHERS
110 AAAAAAAA
111  BBBBBBB
222  CCCCCCC
333  DDDDDD
NEWFILE=CLASSES
1 CLASS-1
2 CLASS-2
```

Comment: How big are your files?
If they are small, you could try this method
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: My file is a single file with records around 10 million. For the small files, if I load the data with wholeTextFiles method, how this will this help me to split the records as per the header.

Comment: As I understand it, The wholeTextFile will put the entire text into on row, so that's not for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-shot ingestion, and as you only have around 10 million
lines, I would probably go for a simple bash script like this:

```
while read LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do
  if [[ $LINE =~ NEWFILE= ]]; then
    FILENAME=${LINE##NEWFILE=}
    echo $FILENAME
  else
    echo $LINE >> $FILENAME 
  fi
done < file
```

Where `file` is the name of your file.

So much for Big Data!

If this has to be done on a regular basis, I would probably ask the developers responsible for this output format to change it to something more standard and easy to parse in a distributed way, like one file per category or maybe Avro.